# Getting error while using sp_helptext on view

Tags: sql-server, view

I am trying to read the code of a 'view' previously created by someone else ,

when i execute this line of code

```
EXEC sp_helptext [view name]
```

i get the following error

```
Msg 15197, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_helptext, Line 110
There is no text for object '_RGEN_ITEMVENEX'.
```

any idea of how to solve this error  ?

Answer (score 0):

you should try to grant VIEW DEFINITION to the desired schema's contained in the database to this role.
Refer to this : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-database-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017